# How do I solve Unmet dependencies error with apt

Tags: apt, package-management

When Ever I try to install something with `apt` it gives me the following error.

```
○ → sudo apt install mysql-server
[sudo] password for galaxy: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs27 : Depends: emacs27-common but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run the command `sudo apt --fix-broken install` it gives me this error.

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs27-common_27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get -f install`, but this also doesn't work.

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs27-common_27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please Help me to solve this.

I am using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

A guy told me to run this and put the output here
`apt-cache policy emacs27 emacs27-common`

```
emacs27:
  Installed: 27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04
  Candidate: 27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04
  Version table:
 *** 27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
emacs27-common:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04
  Version table:
     27.1~1.git86d8d76aa3-kk2+20.04 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kelleyk/emacs/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Do you really use Emacs27? Please run `apt-cache policy emacs27 emacs27-common` and add output of this command to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert Okay I ran the command and I have edit the question too.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use Emacs27, you can purge its PPA by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kelleyk/emacs
```

and then install upgrades and interrupted packages by

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get upgrade
```